# Glib::Regex returns junk, but equivalent C functions work fine

Tags: c++, gtkmm, glibmm

I'm trying to use the Glib::Regex, but it keeps returning junk.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
void testGetPos(std::string fileName){
    auto regEx = Glib::Regex::create(
        "^sprite_[0-9]+__x(-?[0-9]+)_y(-?[0-9]+)\\.tif$",
        Glib::REGEX_CASELESS
    )

    Glib::MatchInfo match;

    if(!regEx->match(fileName, match)){
        continue;
    }

    if(!match.matches()){
        continue;
    }

    auto posX = match.fetch(1);
    auto posY = match.fetch(2);

    // ... Use posX and posY
}

int main(){
    testGetPos("sprite_000__x-28_y-32.tif");
}
```

After this has run, posX and posY are filled with junk. However, using C functions on the wrapped objects:

```
void testGetPos(std::string fileName){
    auto regEx = Glib::Regex::create(
        "^sprite_[0-9]+__x(-?[0-9]+)_y(-?[0-9]+)\\.tif$",
        Glib::REGEX_CASELESS
    )

    GMatchInfo *match = nullptr;
    if(!g_regex_match(regEx->gobj(), fileName.c_str(), (GRegexMatchFlags)0, &match)){
        if(match != nullptr){
            g_match_info_free(match);
        }
        return;
    }

    auto posX = g_match_info_fetch(match, 1);
    auto posY = g_match_info_fetch(match, 2);

    // ... Use posX and posY

    g_free(posX);
    g_free(posY);
    g_match_info_free(match);
}

int main(){
    testGetPos("sprite_000__x-28_y-32.tif");
}
```

Works fine. Am I doing something wrong or is this broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after writing this question, I tried one more thing and that fixed it. Thought I'd better document it here in case someone else hits the same issue.

I changed the equivalent of:

```
void testGetPos(std::string fileName){
```

to something like this:

```
void testGetPos(std::string _fileName){
    Glib::ustring fileName = Glib::filename_to_utf8(_fileName);
```

TL;DR: Was passing an implicitly created temporary to `regEx->match` and `Glib::MatchInfo` needs to access the `Glib::ustring` reference.

Turns out that the problem is this: `regEx->match(fileName, match)` takes `const Glib::ustring &` as its first parameter, but I was passing it `const std::string &` which was being implicitly converted. In most cases, this would be fine, however, the `GMatchInfo` object under the hood of `Glib::MatchInfo` **does not** copy the string that is passed to the match function and it **needs** that data to be available until the object is freed. When I call `regEx->match` with a `std::string` parameter, a temporary `Glib::ustring` object is created while `regEx->match` is executing and is destroyed after it finishes. This means that the data that `Glib::MatchInfo` is accessing is now invalid and therefore junk is returned. By using `Glib::filename_to_utf8`, I create a variable with a lifetime that exceeds the use of the `Glib::MatchInfo` object that is using it, and use and appropriate conversion function.

Hopefully, this helps anyone else that encounters this.